# Meteor command showing ctrl-c option to stop while trying to run the app

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor. When i try to run meteor app in cmd prompt is showing `ctrl-c option to stop the app.`

When I enter `y or n` option the app gets stopped and I am unable to connect with **mongo db**. It is showing an error that meteor is not running a local mongodb server. It is mentioned to start the app first with meteor command.

Someone please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, that's right. when running locally, the mongodb instance attached to your application is started when you run meteor, and stops running when you stop meteor.

in a real production application, you would have a mongo instance that is separate. e.g. running on mLab or Atlas. then you would start your meteor app with a settings file that specified the setting string(s) to connect to the database.